# How to sort a csv file without headers using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

How can I sort a csv file which is without header using python pandas?
NOTE: The csv file is without headers.

My File:

```
1,a123,adam,student
2,b345,becky,student
3,c678,charles,teacher
1,d987,dickson,teacher
2,e654,evanston,teacher
```

Expected output:

```
1,a123,adam,student
1,d987,dickson,teacher
2,b345,becky,student
2,e654,evanston,teacher
3,c678,charles,teacher
```

Comment: do you think sorting by first value of csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `names` for new columns names of `Dataframe` and then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""1,a123,adam,student

2,b345,becky,student

3,c678,charles,teacher

1,d987,dickson,teacher

2,e654,evanston,teacher"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), names=['a','b','c','d'])

print (df)
   a     b         c        d
0  1  a123      adam  student
1  2  b345     becky  student
2  3  c678   charles  teacher
3  1  d987   dickson  teacher
4  2  e654  evanston  teacher

df = df.sort_values('a')
print (df)
   a     b         c        d
0  1  a123      adam  student
3  1  d987   dickson  teacher
1  2  b345     becky  student
4  2  e654  evanston  teacher
2  3  c678   charles  teacher
```

Or use `header=None` for default columns names - `RangeIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None)

print (df)
   0     1         2        3
0  1  a123      adam  student
1  2  b345     becky  student
2  3  c678   charles  teacher
3  1  d987   dickson  teacher
4  2  e654  evanston  teacher

df = df.sort_values(0)
print (df)
   0     1         2        3
0  1  a123      adam  student
3  1  d987   dickson  teacher
1  2  b345     becky  student
4  2  e654  evanston  teacher
2  3  c678   charles  teacher
```

Comment: I think this ques needs some work. The title is `groupby()` while the expected output is `sort`

Comment: @jezrael I have millions of rows in that csv file, can I really assign it to temp variable like you did?

Comment: @Aakib - No, you miss my comment `#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'` ;)

Comment: @Aakib - So need `df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', names=['a','b','c','d'])`

Comment: @jezrael:  df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv', header = None)
>>> df1 = df.sort_values(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1978, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name)) 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: @Aakib - What is your pandas version?

Comment: Problem solved it worked. thanks. But what if I want to get rid of the index too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177899/discussion-between-aakib-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Aakib - There is some problem?

Comment: @Aakib, to get rid of header, use the param header=False in your to_csv function